# How can I wrap a description term in a macro?

Tags: lists

This syntax obviously doesn't work, but it's the gist of what I want to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\DoSomething[1]{Hello, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[label=\DoSomething{*}]
  \item[Duck] ([Hello, Duck] is the label.)
  \item[Duck] ([Hello, Duck] is the label.)
  \item[Goose] ([Hello, Duck] is the label.)
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

To clarify, I want the same effect as saying

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\DoSomething[1]{Hello, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[\DoSomething{Duck}] ([Hello, Duck] is the label.)
  \item[\DoSomething{Duck}] ([Hello, Duck] is the label.)
  \item[\DoSomething{Goose}] ([Hello, Goose] is the label.)
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what you want.

Comment: @Sigur Edited – does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why doesn’t

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\DoSomething[1]{Hello, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\textbf{\DoSomething{#1}}}
    \item[Duck] ([Hello, Duck] is the label.)
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

fulfill your needs?

Comment: Well, because I didn't know about `\makelabel` :) Although I would like to incorporate it into `enumitem`'s configuration interface. Would you mind if I edited your answer to accommodate that one I figure it out?

Comment: @SeanAllread: Do you mean, going something like `\begin{description}[before={\renewcommand*\makelabel[1]{...}}]`?  Well, why not?  Go for it.  But I always prefer not to load packages if I can avoid loading them… :-)

Comment: Fair enough :-) Took me a while to find `before`, but I guess as long as it's in the comments it's a good-enough reference. And I'm developing a résumé package for a friend, so there's going to be a `timeline` list – `enumitem` just makes the process easier for me :-)